# Converting [[Maybe Int]] to IO ()

Tags: haskell

After going through a couple of chapters of "Learn You A Haskell", I wanted to write something hands on and decided to implement a Sudoku solver.I am trying to implement the B1 function from here: http://www.cse.chalmers.se/edu/year/2013/course/TDA555/lab3.html

My code:

```
data Sudoku = Sudoku { getSudoku :: [[Maybe Int]] } deriving (Show, Eq)

rows :: Sudoku -> [[Maybe Int]]
rows (Sudoku rs) = rs

example :: Sudoku
example = Sudoku
    [ [Just 3, Just 6, Nothing,Nothing,Just 7, Just 1, Just 2, Nothing,Nothing]
    , [Nothing,Just 5, Nothing,Nothing,Nothing,Nothing,Just 1, Just 8, Nothing]
    , [Nothing,Nothing,Just 9, Just 2, Nothing,Just 4, Just 7, Nothing,Nothing]
    , [Nothing,Nothing,Nothing,Nothing,Just 1, Just 3, Nothing,Just 2, Just 8]
    , [Just 4, Nothing,Nothing,Just 5, Nothing,Just 2, Nothing,Nothing,Just 9]
    , [Just 2, Just 7, Nothing,Just 4, Just 6, Nothing,Nothing,Nothing,Nothing]
    , [Nothing,Nothing,Just 5, Just 3, Nothing,Just 8, Just 9, Nothing,Nothing]
    , [Nothing,Just 8, Just 3, Nothing,Nothing,Nothing,Nothing,Just 6, Nothing]
    , [Nothing,Nothing,Just 7, Just 6, Just 9, Nothing,Nothing,Just 4, Just 3]
    ]

printSudoku :: Sudoku -> IO ()
printSudoku s = do
    print . map (map (\x -> if isNothing x then 0 else fromJust x)) $ rows s
```

I am trying to get it to print as

```
Sudoku> printSudoku example
36..712..
.5....18.
..92.47..
....13.28
4..5.2..9
27.46....
..53.89..
.83....6.
..769..43
```

but I can only get it to print as

```
[[3,6,0,0,7,1,2,0,0],[0,5,0,0,0,0,1,8,0],[0,0,9,2,0,4,7,0,0],[0,0,0,0,1,3,0,2,8],[4,0,0,5,0,2,0,0,9],[2,7,0,4,6,0,0,0,0],[0,0,5,3,0,8,9,0,0],[0,8,3,0,0,0,0,6,0],[0,0,7,6,9,0,0,4,3]]
```

I apologize if this is the wrong place for such beginner questions. It's just that I have been trying for a while and getting stuck on something relatively trivial and its getting frustrating. Thanks

Comment: `putStrLn $ unlines $ map (map (head.show)) s` and replace 0

Comment: I'd go with `mapM_ (putStrLn . map (maybe '.' Data.Char.intToDigit))` but that's not going to work for 4x4 sudokus...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are very near!

The key point is this anonymous function:

```
(\x -> if isNothing x then 0 else fromJust x)
```

BTW, there are 2 warning flags here: The use of `isNothing`  and `fromJust`.

Now, as this function returns numbers, you can have only numbers displayed. But you want characters instead. Hence, just rewrite this as a local function like:

```
 showcell Nothing  = '.'
 showcell (Just n) = ....
```

=== EDIT: More general advice ===

Whenever you find yourself writing:

```
if isNothing x then a else f (fromJust x)
```

you should replace it with an explicit local function or

```
maybe a f x
```

In your case, you'd initially written just:

```
(\x -> maybe 0 id x)
```

which reduces to the much nicer

```
maybe 0 id
```

and now you just had to change it to:

```
maybe '.' (head . show)
```

or something.

Comment: Oh, I did do the proper import
    import Data.Maybe (isJust, fromJust, isNothing)
Or did you mean that its a bad thing to use those functions that way?

Comment: @dtan Though the way you used them here is safe, pattern matching is generally preferred. Note that `isNothing` needs to deconstruct the value, but `fromJust` needs again to deconstruct it. I show you an alternative.

Comment: Thanks! I managed to get it finally, combining your answer and josejuan's. 
` putStrLn . unlines . map (map showcell) $ rows s` and then doing the pattern matching within showcell.

Comment: Thanks! The examples you showed are so much more elegant.